# Open file in Excel 2016 using AppleScript

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, excel-2016

In Excel 2016, the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open "Macintosh HD:Users:path:to:file"
end tell
```

opens a dialog asking the user to grant access [image: screenshot]
With previous Excel's versions, the file opened immediately.
It seems that Microsoft doesn't allow any more to open a file from a script without the express user permission. 
Is there a way to bypass the dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **file** object or an **alias** object instead of a string

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open file "Macintosh HD:Users:path:to:file"
    -- or --> open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:path:to:file"
end tell
```

When you have a POSIX path, you can use this (`open POSIX file "..."` doesn't work)

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set my_file to POSIX file "/Users/name/path/to/file"
    open my_file
end tell
```

Comment: this is not working in high sierra. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This opens the selected files

```
tell application "Finder"
    open selection with MicrosoftExcel
end tell
```

MacOS 10.14 Mojave | Excel for Mac 16.20

Answer (score 0):

I use this scriptlet to work around the access permissions dialog:

```
'with timeout of 10 seconds
    try
        -- File open may time out due to Apple's sandbox security rules. 
        open FileName
    on error        
        -- A Cancel and Grant Access dialog pops up and stops execution. Click the Grant Access button.
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel" to tell button "Grant Access" of window "Open" of application process "Microsoft Excel" of application "System Events" to perform action "AXPress"
    end try
end timeout'
```

Excel version: 16.32, Mac OS version: 10.14.6